# create sports league table in Android

Tags: android

I am building an app for a local sports league. I would like to add stats and a league table like this: http://www.ihact.org.au/stats but do not know where to start. I have looked through the forums but can only find posts on league tables in other mediums i.e. web. I want to be able to update it without releasing a new version every week. I have looked at databases which I think may be the answer but do not know where to start. If someone could offer a good start point that would be great? I have built the rest of the app already just stuck in this part now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very wide open question but maybe these tips will help. This is how i'd start but others will have their opinion. These answers are very general.

1. You should create a website with a database that you can change with the new stats. This is the easiest way to update your stats each week.
2. You can make the app use a webview and just load the pages from your website or just have them use their browser on their phone.
3. If you want a more interactive app, you will have to have it connect to your webserver to d/l the latest stats. This is the easiest way and you can use AsyncTask to do the d/l and plug it into a SQLite DB.
4. Having a new version of the app each week is the absolute worst way to go.

Here is a [link](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/) that explains AsyncTask for doing the d/l.
[This article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) is very good for understanding all you need to know about SQLite such as how to create it and a content provider.

Comment: A bit more information, i am looking at setting up a database of sports results in the GCE, and then creating an app that will call the information to create a league table.  i have done a lot of searching to find a good tutorial for this but cannot find one if anyone could point me in the right direction.